# Does AngularJS promise scheduling work with `async`/`await`?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, async-await, es6-promise, angular-promise

TypeScript constantly suggests that I change my AngularJS service code to `async`/`await` functions.

[image: TypeScript suggestion]

My understanding is that using the `await` keyword is totally fine with third-party promises, since it is just syntax sugar for calling `then`. However, I normally return Angular promises because they are necessary to play nicely with the digest cycle.

[image: TypeScript error]

This code gives me an error because `async` functions wrap their contents in an ES6 promise. Will this matter for Angular scheduling, given that the returned promise is still hooked up to an Angular-spawned promise? Or should I submit an issue to TypeScript for suggesting `async`/`await` when functions do not explicitly return an ES6 promise?

Comment: The ES6 promises created by `async/await` execute outside the AngularJS execution context. AngularJS modifies the normal JavaScript flow by providing its own event processing loop. This splits the JavaScript into classical and AngularJS execution context. Only operations which are applied in the AngularJS execution context will benefit from AngularJS data-binding, exception handling, property watching, etc.

Comment: See [You should not post code as an image because...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @georgeawg I posted the images specifically because I wanted to show the TypeScript tooltips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone viewing this in the future. It does not play nicely. `async` functions wrap their contents in a global ES6 promise, so if you await AngularJS promises within the changes will eventually hit, but scheduling is weird when you chain together `$q` promises and ES6 promises, so there will usually be an artificial delay before changes are reflected in the DOM.

**On the other hand, Angular 2+ monkey-patches DOM event sources and promises, so `async-await` should work as expected with newer versions.**